# How do I add data labels to a map in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I can plot the depth and time averaged salinity data below as a map of the North Sea (see below), but ideally I'd like the data plotted on top of each grid point.

```
import xarray as xa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmocean.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sns
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat
import cartopy
import cartopy.mpl.geoaxes

data_model = xa.open_dataset("tavg_enhancedhu3_1_x1.nc", decode_times = False)
data_extract = data_model[["O_sal","L_rivers","F_rivdis","F_precip","F_evap","G_areaT"]]

# Change the longitude values from 0 - 360 to -180 - 180
long1 = data_extract.longitude.values
long1[long1>180]-=360
data_extract["longitude"] = long1
data_sorted = data_extract.sortby("longitude")

sal = data_sorted.O_sal

# Select data to include the open ocean around the shelf sea for the same time steps
salt_ocean = sal.sel(longitude=slice(-13,16),
                     latitude=slice(50,65),
                     time=slice(35007,35008))
# Create time-averaged and depth-averaged data 
salt_ocean = salt_ocean.mean("time").mean("depth")
salt_ocean.plot()
```

salt_ocean data:

```
<xarray.DataArray (latitude: 8, longitude: 8)>
array([[35.44104754, 35.46419863,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [35.43968695,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [35.39122538, 35.37911713,         nan, 33.60595351, 33.23583618,
        33.07923434,         nan,         nan],
       [35.34454544, 35.35654288,         nan, 33.90898191, 33.42431083,
        33.14339799,         nan,         nan],
       [35.34184453, 35.35049203,         nan, 34.60941329, 34.01202715,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [35.34375365, 35.34402514, 35.33485814, 35.27626173, 34.83094934,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [35.3026766 , 35.26596918, 35.24030567, 35.21450378, 35.16515657,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [35.10408352, 35.04095948, 34.94321486, 34.98362822, 35.09360272,
        35.07035372,         nan,         nan]])
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -12.6 -9.0 -5.4 -1.8 1.8 5.4 9.0 12.6
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 51.3 53.1 54.9 56.7 58.5 60.3 62.1 63.9
```

[image]

I haven't had any success in trying some of the solutions on other stackoverflow questions, as I've only been able to find examples for line or bar charts.

To hopefully make this issue easier to replicate, I've created a dataarray with the same dimensions as my actual data (although the random data isn't exactly realistic.

```
data = 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(8, 8)
salinity = xa.DataArray(data)
salinity = xa.DataArray(data, dims=['lat', 'lon'])
lons = np.linspace(-13, 16, 8)
lats = np.linspace(50, 65, 8)
salinity = xa.DataArray(data, coords=[lats, lons], dims=['lat', 'lon'])
salt_ocean = salinity
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please, indicate which framework/library you are using and add it also as a tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a cartopy user and I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly so I'm a little bit hesitant to reply but I think this is standard functionality in cartopy. In particular, you are going to want to set a projection and use something like `ax.stock_img()` to place a map down. Then some command like `plt.scatter(longitudes, latitudes, c=data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())`
should plot scatter points colored by the data you have (salinity data or whatever) on top of that map.
You can narrow the region plotted down with the command `ax.set_extent([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2], crs=crs.PlateCarree())` to only give you the north sea.

https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/intro.html